# how to redraw point with delay from one point to other point (android)?

Tags: android

how to redraw point with delay from one point  to other point (android)? these code below it delay the hold drawing , what i want is delay from one point to other point.

public void reDraw2()
    {

```
    drawPaint.setColor(0xFF660000);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    //alphabetDrawingCanvasGlobal.recordPoints;     
    int cnt = 0;
    for(final PointF point: recordPoints) { 
        // System.out.println("touchX>>" + point.x + "TouchY>>" + point.y);
        if (cnt == 0) {

                    // do something here like draw text;
                      drawPath.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
                      try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            cnt++;
        } else {

                    // do something here like draw text;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                      drawPath.lineTo(point.x, point.y);


        }
        invalidate();

    }
```

Comment: TYour answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130888/draw-lines-perodically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a horrible way of doing it.  The better way to do it is to set up a timer.  When the timer goes off, update the position of everything you want to draw, then invalidate the view.  Then let the onDraw function draw it again, which will grab the new position info.

Comment: thanks for your advice, could you give me some example code, because i'm a new starter .